# how to use SQL user defined function in snowflake?

Tags: sql, function, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am just studying how to use SQL in snowflake. Here is a snapshot:

[image]

And this is the code used in here:

```
use schema SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1;
--use schema SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF10;

select *
from LINEITEM
limit 200
```

You can see the table includes two feilds: L_LINENUMBER, L_QUANTITY. Now I want to try a user defined function, which can do:

1. use L_LINENUMBER, L_QUANTITY as two parameters transferred into the function,
2. calculate L_LINENUMBER1=L_LINENUMBER+1, and L_QUANTITY1=mean(L_QUANTITY).
3. join the two new fields (L_LINENUMBER1, L_QUANTITY1) to the original table (LINEITEM)

how to use create function to do this. I have read a lot of examples regarding create function. But I just cannot get the point. Maybe because I am not good at SQL. So, could anyone give me a comprehensive example with all the details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you question is about UDFs, but using UDFs for your purpose here is overkill.

You can increment an attribute in a table using the following statement.

```
SELECT
    L_LINENUMBER+1 as L_LINENUMBER1
FROM LINEITEM;
```

To calculate the mean of an attribute in a table, you should understand that this is an aggregate function which only makes sense when used in conjunction with a group by statement. An example with your data is shown below.

```
SELECT
    AVG(L_QUANTITY) AS L_QUANTITY1
FROM LINEITEM
GROUP BY L_ORDERKEY;
```

Since your question was originally on UDFs and you seem to be following with Snowflake's sample data, the example that they provide is the following UDF which accepts a temperature in Kelvin and converts it to Fahrenheit (from the definition you can see that it can be applied to any attribute of the number type).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
  UTIL_DB.PUBLIC.convert_fahrenheit( t NUMBER)
  RETURNS NUMBER
  COMMENT='Convert from Kelvin from Fahrenheit'
  AS '(t - 273.15) * 1.8000 + 32.00';
```