# How to write user-defined functions in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I am very new to Snowflake. Till now I had used Teradata for writing complex SQL queries.
In snowflake, I need to create and call macros (similar to Teradata), where I have to pass date as parameters, and within the function I have to append records in a table. Something along these lines:

```
CREATE TABLE SFAAP.WS_DIRBNK_DPST.PV_HIGH_RISK_FI_LIST
(
APP_DT DATE
,FI_NAME VARCHAR(50)  
);



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SFAAP.INSERT_FI (DT DATE, CRED CHAR(5))
    --RETURNS NULL
    --COMMENT='Create list of high risk FI by date'
    AS 
    '
    INSERT INTO SFAAP.WS_DIRBNK_DPST.PV_HIGH_RISK_FI_LIST
    TO_DATE(DD)             --------------Passed Parameter
    ,FI_NAME
    FROM  
    (
    SELECT
    FINANCIAL_INSTITUTION AS FI_NAME
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN IND_FPFA_FRAUD = 1 THEN APP_ID ELSE NULL END) AS TOT_FPFA_APPS 
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT APP_ID) AS TOT_APPS
    ,CAST(TOT_FPFA_APPS AS DECIMAL(38,2))/TOT_APPS AS FRAUD_RATE
    FROM
        (
        SELECT
        A.*
        ,C.FINANCIAL_INSTITUTION
        FROM BASE_05 A
        LEFT JOIN 
                (
                SELECT
                BNK_ACCT_NBR_TOK
                ,BNK_TRAN_TYP_CDE 
                ,ALT_DR_CR_CDE
                ,TRAN_1_DSC_TOK
                ,TRAN_DT
                ,TRAN_AMT
                FROM "SFAAP"."V_SOT_DIRBNK_CLB_FRD_CRD"."BNK_DPS_TRAN_RLT_INFO" 
                WHERE TRAN_DT BETWEEN DATEADD(Day,-90,TO_DATE(DD)) AND TO_DATE(DD)   --------------Passed Parameter, does calculation in the 90 days window from the passed date
                AND ALT_DR_CR_CDE = TO_CHAR(CRED) --------------Passed Parameter
                AND BNK_TRAN_TYP_CDE IN (22901,56003,56002,56302,56303,56102,70302)
                AND TRAN_AMT>=5
                QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BNK_ACCT_NBR_TOK, TRAN_DT, TRAN_AMT, BNK_TRAN_TYP_CDE  ORDER BY TRAN_DT ASC, TRAN_AMT DESC)=1
                ) B
                ON A.BNK_ACCT_NBR = B.BNK_ACCT_NBR_TOK 

                LEFT JOIN SFAAP.WS_DIRBNK_DPST.PV_FRAUD_METRICS_03 C
                ON B.TRAN_1_DSC_TOK = C.TOKEN_NAME
        )SUB_A
    GROUP BY 1
    )SUB_B
    WHERE FINANCIAL_INSTITUTION IS NOT NULL  
    AND TOT_APPS>=3
    AND FRAUD_RATE>=0.20
    '
    ;
```

I took some guidance from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55349660/how-to-use-sql-user-defined-function-in-snowflake), but I am still not there yet. Here's the error which I am getting:

[image]

Due to lack of experience writing snowflake user-defined functions, I think I am messing up syntax somewhere (could be the way I am passing those two parameters). Comments/suggestions are most welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like SFAAP is your database name, please include your schema name if you are going to use "Fully Qualified Names", or change your session context to use a database and schema and then create the function without the database and schema name.

example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SFAAP.WS_DIRBNK_DPST.INSERT_FI (
```

Comment: Thanks Rich for your suggestion. Looks like I am hitting a new error which says `SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'WS_DIRBNK_DPST'`. Let me talk with admin folks in my company.

Comment: Since the answer helped you get past your original error, please consider taking a moment to "accept" the answer and asking a new question for the schema permission error you are having (docs link on that https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/grant-privilege.html)

Comment: Does passing of the parameters look OK to you? I could not know because I don't have privilege yet. Just making sure the rest of the syntax looks OK/error-free.

Comment: @Piyush Verma  You are trying to  do Insert Operations in UDFs, which i doubt you could do these DML:s in SQL UDFs, Just Check the documentation.https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql.html